# Alter code to Remove instead of Allow characters

Tags: excel, udf, vba

The function `allows` the character listed (in this case)

```
Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122:
```

Is it possible to change this to `Remove` the characters listed instead?

Thanks

```
Function AlphaNumericOnly(strSource As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strResult As String

    For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
            Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122:
                strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    AlphaNumericOnly = strResult
End Function
```

Comment: They both came from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723672/how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-period-and-sp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use `For ... Next` - just add `Case Else`:

```
    For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
            Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122:
            Case Else:
                strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
```

As @pnuts pointed and @brettdj [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27579035/2165759) - RegEx is more efficient, in your case the function may be as follows:

```
Function NonAlphaNumericOnly(strSource As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "[\w]+"
        NonAlphaNumericOnly = .Replace(strSource, "")
    End With
End Function
```