# UltimateCleanSheet Code errors

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to write a `Clean sheet` Sub

First:

Some serial #'s from the data I get will start with `-` which is a problem in excel, I want to replace all cell content that `starts` with `-` and replace it with `@` `replace()` does `not` work

This is erroring:

```
.Value = Evaluate("if(row(" & .Address & "),""@"" & Right(" & .Address & ", Len(" & .Address & ") - 2))")
```

It turns all cells to `#NAME?`

2nd:

I Changed this

```
 MyArray(x, y) = RemoveChars(MyArray(x, y)
```

To this

```
 If Not IsError(MyArray(x, y)) Then
         MyArray(x, y) = RemoveChars(MyArray(x, y))
 End If
```

Because the code ran (Sans the line of code from Question 1) the first time but if I ran it a second time on the same data sheet it errored

What would cause the code to error on the second run?

Does adding the `If Not IsError(MyArray(x, y))` interfere with the removal of unwanted characters?

The `UDF` came from Here:

[Alter code to Remove instead of Allow characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192616/alter-code-to-remove-instead-of-allow-characters)

```
Sub UltimateCleanSheet()
Dim HL As Hyperlink
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CL As Range
Dim txt As String
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, x As Long, y As Long

goFast False
For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("OriginalData", "NewData"))
 With ws

      'Get error if sheet not selected
      ws.Select

      'Reset UsedRange
      Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

      'Create Array
      MyArray = ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)

     'Remove unwanted Characters
     'http://www.ascii-code.com/
     For x = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
         For y = LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2)

         If Not IsError(MyArray(x, y)) Then
               MyArray(x, y) = RemoveChars(MyArray(x, y))
         End If

         Next y
     Next x

    'Postback to sheet
    .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0) = MyArray
 End With

 With ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)

    'Clear all formulas
    .Value = .Value

    'Replace "Non-breaking space" with ""
    .Replace what:=Chr(160), replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlPart

    'Replace carriage Return with ", "
    .Replace what:=Chr(13), replacement:=", ", lookat:=xlPart

    'Replace hyphen if 1st char with "@"
    .Value = Evaluate("if(row(" & .Address & "),""@"" & Right(" & .Address & ", Len(" & .Address & ") - 2))")

    'Clean, Trim
    .Value = Evaluate("if(row(" & .Address & "),clean(trim(" & .Address & ")))")
End With

'Turn live hyperlinks to text
For Each HL In ws.Hyperlinks
    Set CL = HL.Parent
    txt = HL.Address & HL.SubAddress
    HL.Delete
    CL.Value = txt
Next HL

Next ws

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
goFast True
End Sub
```

UDF:

```
Function RemoveChars(ByVal strSource As String) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strResult As String

For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
        Case 0, 9, 10, 12, 33, 161 To 255:

        Case Else:
            strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)

    End Select
Next i

RemoveChars = strResult

End Function
```

Comment: Did you try `ws.UsedRange.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="'@", LookAt:=xlPart` (or `Replacement:="""@"""`)

Comment: Am I missing it? Is `aCell` declared anywhere in your code?

Comment: `aCell` was a mistake I have changed my code to reflect this.  Sorry about that, still errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much ado I came up with

Edit Addition and improvment

```
'Sheet Names To Clean
'ID Column Number
'Name (e.g John Doe) Column Number
'Dilimiter to Replace carriage Returns with
Sub CleanSheets()

  fCleanSheets Array("Elements", "Connections"), 1, 2, ", "

End Sub
```

Sub:

```
Sub fCleanSheets(arrShtNames As Variant, IdColNub As Long, LabelColNub As Long,   Optional iDiliter As String = ", ")
Dim HL As Hyperlink
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CL As Range, Rng, aCell As Range
Dim txt As String
Dim x As Long, y As Long

For Each ws In Worksheets(arrShtNames)
 With ws
  'IF Get error if sheet not selected then uncomment
  'ws.Select

  'Reset UsedRange
  Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

  'TextWrap
   Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.WrapText = False

  'Turn live hyperlinks to text
  For Each HL In ws.Hyperlinks
    Set CL = HL.Parent
    txt = HL.Address & HL.SubAddress
    HL.Delete
    CL.Value = txt
  Next HL

  'Remove all Formulas
  With ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
    .Value = .Value
  End With

  'Create Array
  MyArray = .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)

 For x = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
     For y = LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2)

     If Not IsError(MyArray(x, y)) Then

         'Remove unwanted Characters
         'http://www.ascii-code.com/
           MyArray(x, y) = RemoveChars_NEWHAB(MyArray(x, y))

         'Trim Sheets(Will NOT error if LEN(string) > 255 char's)
           MyArray(x, y) = Trim(MyArray(x, y))

         'Replace carriage Return with dilimiter
           MyArray(x, y) = Replace(MyArray(x, y), Chr(13), iDiliter)
           MyArray(x, y) = Replace(MyArray(x, y), Chr(10), iDiliter)

     End If

     Next y

     'ONLY APPLYING ON CERTIN COLUMNS
        'If FIRST char = "-" Replace it on ID Column ONLY
           If Left(MyArray(x, IdColNub), 1) = "-" Then
              MyArray(x, IdColNub) = "@" & Right(MyArray(x, IdColNub), Len(MyArray(x, IdColNub)) - 1)
           End If

        'Convert Accented letters to NON Accented letters on Label Column ONLY
          MyArray(x, LabelColNub) = ConvertAccent(MyArray(x, LabelColNub))

        'Remove Mulutiple Spaces Between Names on Label Column ONLY
          MyArray(x, LabelColNub) =  Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(MyArray(x, LabelColNub))

 Next x

'Postback to sheet
.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0) = MyArray
End With

Next ws

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select

End Sub
```

UDF: RemoveChars

```
Function RemoveChars(ByVal strSource As String) As String
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723672/how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-period-and-sp
Dim i As Integer
Dim strResult As String

For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
        Case 2, 0, 9, 10, 12, 160, 161 To 255: 'http://www.ascii-code.com/

        Case Else:
            strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)

    End Select
Next i

RemoveChars = strResult

End Function
```

UDF: ConvertAccent

```
 Function ConvertAccent(ByVal inputString As String) As String
 ' http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-483965.html
 Dim x As Long, Position As Long
 Const AccChars As String = _
    "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
 Const RegChars As String = _
    "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"
 For x = 1 To Len(inputString)
   Position = InStr(AccChars, Mid(inputString, x, 1))
   If Position Then Mid(inputString, x) = Mid(RegChars, Position, 1)
Next
ConvertAccent = inputString
End Function
```